# How to handle the authorize pop-up in Robot Framework

Tags: popup, robotframework

At the moment I'm trying to access a website using Robot Framework Automation.
But when navigating to the target url, this pop-up shows asking the username/ password.

[image: Authorize Popup]

I tried to do following methods below but not success:

- Inspect the element: No element return
- AutoIT: AutoIT just detect the current browser not the pop-up itself
- Click with Coordinator: I tried to handle it with X, Y Coordinate but it still need the attribute locator that I cannot find.

So please help to give the idea about this case?

Comment: what GUI tech/stack is using your application under test?

Comment: We're using VueJS

Answer (score 0):

How do you navigate to webpage? Is it `Go To    https://example.com/`? If yes than try `Go To    https://username:password@example.com/`

Comment: This assumes that a Basic authentication is used, which may not be the case and is difficult to asses from the image alone.

Comment: Tried with your suggestion and it returns ez@myurl.com